# Q. Interop.Excel opens two instances of File

Tags: c#, windows, excel, excel-interop

I Have a C# program that creates an Excel file report from a .txt file.

It works perfect, but sometimes (often) when I opened a spreadsheet Excel opens 2 spreadsheets:

1 for my saved file.
1 with some trash data called "Plan1" which is not saved.

I'm not sure where excel find the trash data to Plan1.

Here is the code to save the spreadsheet:

```
protected string ExportOC(Application app, OcFile oc, bool configurator) 
{
    string ocFinalName;
    if (configurator)
        ocFinalName = string.Format("{0}{1}", ocFinalName = oc.Name, Models.Constants.CHECK_CONFIGURATOR);
    else if (oc.Error)
        ocFinalName = string.Format("{0}{1}", ocFinalName = oc.Name, Models.Constants.CHECK_STRUCT_ERROR);
    else
        ocFinalName = string.Format("{0}{1}", ocFinalName = oc.Name, Models.Constants.CHECK_OK);
    try 
    {
        string savePath = string.Format("{0}{1}", Importer.GetPathWithType(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Modelos.Constants.SAVE_ROOT_PATH].ToString(), oc.Type), ocFinalName);
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;
        app.ActiveWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;
        app.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(savePath, XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Missing.Value,Missing.Value, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution,true,Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
        return string.Format("{0}{1}", ocFinalName, Models.Constants.EXTENSION_EXCEL_X);
    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        return InvalidOC(oc, Models.Constants.CHECK_NO_SAVED);
    } finally 
    {
        ClearCOM(app);
    }
}
```

and here is how I clean the COM Object:

```
protected void ClearCOM(Application app) 
{
    try 
    {
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;
        app.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0);
        app.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
    }
    catch 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I should put the code to open the spreadsheet here, because this problem occurs even when I open the file outside the program (more often than inside as long as I concern).

Thanks for the help

**EDIT**

the worksheet's name must have Special Characters like: 5198416384684_003
here is how I create the COM Objects.

```
public string ProcessOC(OcFile oc) {
    Application app = new Application();
    Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
    Worksheet plan = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
    plan.Name = oc.Name; 
    bool rightSize = false;
    bool haveMoreDocuments = false;
    int indexLine = 1, indexColumn = 1;
    int lin = 1, col = 0;
    string columnLetter = String.Empty;
    string ajusteTextoNum = String.Empty;

    try {
        List<string> validLines = GetValidContent(oc.Lines);

        foreach (string line in validLines) {
            //get the txt lines and put all of them im the worksheet
        }

        // format the worksheet 

        return ExportOC(app, oc, false);

    } catch (WrongPrinterException) {
        return InvalidOC(oc, Modelos.Constants.CHECK_NO_PRINTER); //doesn't save
    } catch (MissingFileException) {
        return InvalidOC(oc, Modelos.Constants.CHECK_MISS_SOURCE_FILE); //doesn't save
    } catch (Exception) {
        return InvalidOC(oc, Modelos.Constants.CHECK_NO_SAVED); //doesn't save
    } finally {
        ClearCOM(app);
    }
}
```

and the problem itself.

[image]

Sorry to omit some values, it's the company politics.
This time, I opened outside the program and those data, isn't really garbage, it's another report with a different format that the operator probably closed before.

Maybe Excel is trying to restore the previously session.

I will try to clean the other COM Objects and use the Marshal.ReleaseComObject too.

**EDIT 2**

I tried to Clear the COM Objects but, still opens 2 spreadsheet at once.

here the code to clear COM

```
protected void ClearCOM(Application app, Workbook workbook, Worksheet worksheet) {
    try {
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;
        app.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
        app.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
    } catch {
        return;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3**

I Already clean the XLSTART folder, still nothing

Comment: can you show the code where you are creating the instance of the ComObject..? make sure that you doing a `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on all of the Excel.Interop Objects.. workbook, worksheet, Application...etc

Comment: I understand that "Plan1" is localized Excel ("Sheet1"). How is the other sheet with the valid data named then? Do you use special characters in the sheet name? Posting more code of how the sheet is created, added and populated, might help. Posting some of the garbage from the other sheet might help too.

Comment: done @dlatikay come and see

Comment: before we look further, let's rule out these two as the cause:
http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/08/18/unwanted-files-open-automatically-when-excel-starts
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826922

Comment: I already done this before @dlatikay both of XLSTART folder and the Excel 'At startup, open all files in' is empty...still nothing.

Comment: @GuilhermeGolfetto Wondering if you found resolution for the issue in your question. I'm having similar problem and so far came up with nothing. Two files are opening after two Excel files merge - "work in progress" file (the unwanted one) and my saved file.

Comment: I would be very interested to know how Guilherme solved this!

Comment: Are you opening the file programmatically or by double-clicking the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who still has this problem. I solved it by creating a `Workbook` with the [`Workbooks.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add?view=excel-pia) method without giving it any parameters.
So in the OPs problem, change this:

```cs
Application app = new Application();
Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
```

To this:

```cs
Application app = new Application();
Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(); // No parameters
```

The `Add` method has an optional `Template` parameter, which can be of the type [`XlWBATemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlwbatemplate?view=excel-pia). The OP used `1` as a value for this parameter, which isn't a valid value in this case.

This is what the documentation says about ignoring the parameter:

> If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook with a number of blank sheets (the number of sheets is set by the SheetsInNewWorkbook property).

Comment: Nice job, I don't work with this company anymore, but if somebody still has this problem, thats one good solution